# Question about the focal length and the position of a convex lens

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, geometric-optics, lenses

How can I determine the focal length and position of a lens mounted in an inaccessible position inside a tube by a laboratory experiment?

Comment: Your question seems a bit vague at the moment. Can you describe the geometry of the experiment i.e. all the distances and positions of the lenses. Also indicate what approaches to the problem you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Take a light source, place it far away from your lens. Then use a screen at the other side of the lens and adjust the distance of the lens and the screen until a sharp image of the light source is obtained. This distance is then the focal length.

Example: place a sheet of paper on the floor. Hold the lens over it and adjust its height so that you see a clear image of the fluorescent tube light of your lab.

Comment: How do you measure the distance from the image to a lens that you can't locate inside its housing?

Comment: @User58220 You may need either to take apart your tube. Make sure you understand a sound alignment procedure so you can put it back together again. Either that, or contact the manufacturer for specifications. The manufacturer in this case might be a former co-worker, who might not be too sure, so Andreas's answer, although it may sound flippant, is seriously what you need to do.

Comment: The OP says the lens is inaccessible; so Andrea's answer is seriously not an answer to the original question...

Comment: Well inaccessible does not mean that you cant measure the distance. Why should it? The lens is at least accessible to light so there must be a path, and some measurement (using in a rod, when the assembly is opened at some end) or at least estimation should be possible.

Comment: Well Grazel does not tell us that the lens can actually be accessed from both ends of some optical axis.   But that is necessary for Andreas' solution to work.   Assuming that is the case, an alternative to Andreas' solution is to use a light to illuminate some object (a transparent grid is good) and project that onto Andreas' screen.   Move the object towards the screen keeping the lens in a central position.  Reduce the object to screen distance, until you get a 1:1 sharp image of the screen (measure it), and at a minimum distance, which will be 4f if the lens is "thin" enough.

Comment: @George: Well Grazel does not tell too much at all! Good alternative solution though, especially since the screen is twice as far away from the lens as compared to my solution. It needs a little bit more work though.